# Denote that something is constant

Tags: math-mode

How do I write that something is constant?
For example I am currently writing:
`p \cdot V = const.`, but that feels wrong. Is there some sort of command to write something like `p \cdot V = \constant`?

Comment: Maybe you want `\text{const}` in math mode.

Comment: choice of notation is really off topic for this site (you could ask on the math site perhaps) Once you have decided on the notation, asking how best to implement that in TeX would be on topic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. However many students learn good typesetting style by exposure to LaTeX manuals.